# grails modalbox redirect back to parent window

Tags: grails

I am new to grails, and I have been trying to get the following functionality to work.

I am using grails modal box, and I have a save button. When I click on save, how can I close the modal box, and pass a variable back to the parent window?

Comment: That plugin hasn't been updated in 2 years.  If I were you, I'd move to something more current like jQueryUI's Dialog or something similar.

Comment: @Gregg. Thanks a lot. Do you suggest any tutorial websites or books where I can find stuff on integrating grails with Jquery UI?

Comment: There is a good plugin for jQuery UI. Just take a look at plugins page. Of course you have to know about jQuery UI itself.

Comment: I've never fully understood trying to integrate client side scripting with a predominantly server side framework.  So I won't suggest using grails plugins for this kind of stuff.  It's not that difficult to add a link to a script in your header.  Everything else is just javascript.  So just look at the jQueryUI website. Lots of demos there.

Answer (score 0):

I think I'm doing what you want in my Customer Change actions in a couple screens at http://ibidem.cloudfoundary.com. Login as ibidem/ibidem and do a Customer Change on a Lookup Table.

Then if this is what you want, see
https://trac.maflt.org/web/ibidem/browser/trunk/src/ibidem/grails-app/views/lookupTable/show.gsp

and the corresponding controller:
https://trac.maflt.org/web/ibidem/browser/trunk/src/ibidem/grails-app/controllers/org/maflt/ibidem/LookupTableController.groovy

Comment: Cloud Foundry is being a bit flaky, so you may or may not be able to actually get to the demo site.